# PHP upgrade after installing phpmyadmin

Tags: apt, apache-httpd, php

I had a Debian Server with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3

I installed phpmyadmin (sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin).

Now, the versions of Apache and PHP have been upgrade (2.4/5.6)

Is this possible? How can I avoid this?

---

`libapache2-mod-php5: Installiert: 5.6.7+dfsg-1 Installationskandidat: 5.6.7+dfsg-1 Versionstabelle: *** 5.6.7+dfsg-1 0 500 http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages/ jessie/main amd64 Packages 500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 5.3.3-7+squeeze19 0 500 http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages 500 http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/security/ squeeze/updates/main amd64 Packages`

---

sources.list:

```
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free


deb     http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages squeeze main contrib non-free
deb     http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/security squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3 were the versions available in Debian Squeeze (Debian 6). Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` points to both Squeeze and Jessie (Debian 8), so when you asked to install `phpmyadmin`, `apt-get` automatically picked the latest acceptable version and its dependencies; these were taken from Jessie.

To avoid this in future, you need to remove the `jessie` lines from `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and ideally add those for Squeeze LTS (see [Using LTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using) for details) to get some security support. You'll need to manually revert `phpmyadmin` and its dependencies; `apt-show-versions` can be used to identify packages which don't match Squeeze.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry that I cant upvote you, have only 8 reputation points so far...